# Curvature tensor of a conformally flat manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n>3$ and $g$ a Riemannian metric on $M$ which is conformally equivalent to a flat one. Are there formulas (different from $R(u,v)w=\nabla_u\nabla_vw-\nabla_v\nabla_uw-\nabla_{[u,v]}w$) that allow to compute easily the curvature tensor of a conformally flat manifold such as $(M,g)$?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change) which describes how various curvatures transform under conformal change a Riemannian metric. Now, apply the formula for the transformation of the full curvature tensor to your situation, taking into account that initially you have a flat metric.